# How to sign XML document or verify XML document signature with C++?

Tags: c++, windows, xml, security, digital-signature

Subj. I need to sign/verify under Windows in native C++ (no .NET), using private key for signing, public key for verification.

I saw few examples on MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms761363(VS.85).aspx) that demonstrate how to sign the document with CSP (I don't know what this means).

For my case I need to use a "key" from the binary data array (using DSA encryption algorithm)... can somebody help me with that?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: CSP = Cryptographic Service Provider, which is a .net thing. Just for your info.

Answer (score 4):

I recommand [libxml2](http://xmlsoft.org/) and [xmlsec](http://www.aleksey.com/xmlsec/) which are perfect for this purpose.

The API can seem hard to read at first, but it works well. [xmlsec](http://www.aleksey.com/xmlsec/) uses [OpenSSL](http://www.openssl.org/source/) to achieve the cryptographic part.

Providing a "short" example here is probably hard because the three libraries require some initialization and a lot of `C` calls.

Comment: ereOn, as far as I see xmlsSec doesn't support DSA, right? I am need it to work with my keys (private for signing/encoding, public for verification). Any other thoughts?
Thanks.

Comment: I admit that I never had to deal with DSA. I know OpenSSL handles DSA just fine and that xmlsec relies on OpenSSL. Maybe there is a way to add a "DSA" handler to xmlsec code ? You should ask the authors on their mailing-list.

Comment: Searching for this same thing got to this answer. Just downloaded binaries for Windows, I'll take a look tonight. Seems promising (there are Delphi bindings provided which is way cool!)

Answer (score 2):

Google's [keyczar](http://www.keyczar.org/) lib is also very easy to use

Comment: Forget to say, that I need that library to be workable under Windows. But current version (0.6b) has limitations. One of them: - Does not work on Windows (should be relatively easy to port it using OpenSSL however it would require much more work to use MS CAPI instead).

Comment: @Budda: I added the "windows" tag to make that obvious.

Answer (score 0):

There's also [Crypto++](http://www.cryptopp.com/)